# Set Windows Explorer As default file explorer

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome, windows-explorer

I installed a different file explorer and when I uninstalled, files open with another explorer. When I click open folder in Chrome, it cannot find a default handler.

I tried checking regedit HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Directory\shell, but not sure what to do there.

Answer (score 0):

Check if **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE>Software>Microsoft>Windows NT>CurrentVersion>Winlogon** has **explorer.exe** value on **Shell**

Comment: It does has explorer.exe for Shell.

Comment: Check the same path ">Software>Microsoft>Windows NT>CurrentVersion>Winlogon" under HLU subfolders

Answer (score 0):

If you have  Windows 7 Professional/Ultimate/Enterprise, go to `Start / Run / gpedit.msc` and in the **Local Group Policy Editor** ensure

`User Configuration / Administrative Templates / System / Custom User Interface`

is set to **Not configured** or **Disabled**.

Comment: Interestingly, I do not have Custom User Interface under System.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't looking under **Computer Configuration** instead of **User Configuration**?

Comment: Yup, I checked both, and it was not under either.

Comment: Strange, that's where it should be in Win7. Perhaps replacing the shell messed up your system more than you know.